# $expand doesn't work after migration and code is first

Tags: asp.net-web-api, odata

could not find a property named on type odata when expand property in uri
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YVD4X.png)

The query specified in the URI is not valid. Could not find a property named 'wallet_client_branch' on type 'System.Web.OData.Query.Expressions.SelectAllAndExpand_1Of